# How can I get sound to play in iOS 11 browsers? (Howler.js/AngularJS)

Tags: audio, mobile-safari, ios11, mobile-browser, howler.js

I built a very simple web app that uses Howler.js to stream music from a SHOUTcast online radio station. It works just as intended in pretty much all instances except iOS 11 browsers (Chrome and Safari), where I can't get any sound to play. Everything works just fine in iOS 10.3 as long as the user clicks the 'play' button (the app is otherwise set to autoplay on desktop browsers). However, there's no sound in iOS 11 even when 'play' is pressed.

I'm very unfamiliar with iOS development. Based on my research, I've tried to create touch event handlers to initiate sound, but that hasn't worked so far. Does anyone have info on why sound would work in iOS 10.3 mobile browsers, but not in iOS 11, and how I might go about troubleshooting that?